# Hybrid AMD/INTEL and tearing

Tags: unity, ati, intel, hybrid, tearing

This is getting really really boring!

Is there any way to get rid of video tearing using `fglrx`? I have a hybrid system with intel hd3000(SandyBridge) and amd 6770m.

I have tried everything like turning `vsync` on from `ccc`, ticking `set vblank` in `compiz settings manager`, setting `1` for `xv` in `vlc`, using `opengl` in `vlc`, enabling gpu acceleration in `vlc`, setting `texture video sync` on in `xorg.conf` and others....

I have video tearing also in youtube. When I use the intel card everything is fine. I have tried also the tearfree desktop even though it's not in `ccc`, I ve enabled it through terminal.

I have used 12.11 beta. Is this fglrx's problem? Unity's? I even tried with `cinnamon`... I was in 12.10 but I downgraded to 12.04 because there were a lot of problems with `fglrx` and `xorg`.

Does anyone know if there's a tear free desktop using hybrid and linux?

Thanks in advance....